# Using CloudKit in a Swift application, is it possible to add the queryable index to the recordName system field in the production infrastructure?

Tags: ios, swift, cloudkit

I am trying to add to the recordName of my CKRecords, the queryable index. Unfortunately, I succeed to do so only in the development environment, not for the production. Is it necessary to have the index already present in development before making the deployment step ? Or is there a way to set it after the environment has been deployed ? I don't find the option in the CloudKit dashboard, it is only available in the development section. Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: you can create the index in development and then delete it before deployment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct. You have to make the change in **development** and then promote the change to your **production** environment. You can always push schema and index changes from development to production, but not in the other direction.

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks a lot Clifton !